# How to send data from Windows to embedded linux over USB

Tags: python, linux, windows, usb, pyserial

My setup looks like this: A 64-bit box running Windows 7 Professional is connected to a Beaglebone running Angstrom Linux.

I'm currently controlling the beaglebone via a putty command line on the windows box.

What I'd like to do is run an OpenCV script to pull some vision information, process it on the windows box, and send some lightweight data (e.g a `True` or `False`, a triplet, etc.) over the (or another) USB connection to the beaglebone.

My OpenCV program is running using Python bindings, so any piping I can do with python would be preferable. I've played around with pyserial to receive data on a windows box via a COM port, so it seems like I could use that on the windows side... at a total loss though on the embedded linux front

Answer (score 0):

Normally on the linux front, if the usb dongle is of the right type, you will see something like /dev/usbserial or similar device. Maybe check dmesg after plugging the cable.
(on linux you can run `find /dev | grep usb` to list all usb related devices)

Just a side note, I've seen the beaglebone has an ethernet port, why not just using a network socket? It's all easier than reinventing a protocol on usb.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python, take a look o [PyUSB](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pyusb/), as you can see for example in [Sending data via USB using PyUSB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313008/sending-data-via-usb-using-pyusb). A related post is [PyUSB for the Raspberry Pi](http://martinsant.net/?p=339).